# postgresql table encryption using PGP public key (pgp_pub_encrypt)

Tags: postgresql, encryption, public-key-encryption, psql, pgp

I have been trying to encrypt a psql table using pgp_pub_encrypt function & I'm able to encrypt when I manually enter the data one-by-one, But I need to encrypt a particular column in my table while inserting it from another table(since the column has n number of values). I tried using a command like this

```
INSERT INTO table2(column2)
SELECT pgp_pub_encrypt(robotccs.column2, keys.pubkey)  
columnn1_from_table1  FROM table1 AS robotccs(cc)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT dearmor('-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
cat & copy the entire key here  
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----') As pubkey) As keys;
```

where column1(bytea) represents the table1's column & column2 represents table2 where the data has to be copied from col-1. I get all sorts of error & the encryption fails. When I type & insert the values manually into table2, the job gets done. Can anyone tell me a way to do this or provide some clear documentation on how pgp encryption is done in a detailed manner. postgresql website doesn not have one.

Comment: I tried ... -- but what happened? It seems the last (and important) part of your question got lost during posting it.

Comment: I tested your code and it seemed to work. On the way I had some minor errors: `ERROR:  No encryption key found` means that the public key is missing the part required to actually encrypt the data. Also making sure that `robotccs.cc` is enterpreted as a string `robotccs.cc::text` might be neccecary depending on your data.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. Yes while posting it something happened I guess. Now I have edited & posted the wholw question. I'm not getting the meaning of  `robotccs` anywhere & why should we use that for encryption